# How can I remove Reply Keyboard (Telegram Bot)

Tags: python-2.7, telegram, telegram-bot

I just need the url to remove the ReplyKeyboard.

I am using Python but not the Python BotLibrary. I do all the work with requests because I want the full flexibility.

Answer (score 7):

I looked it up and tested it in PHP:

```
$removeKeyboard = array('remove_keyboard' => true);
$removeKeyboardEncoded = json_encode($removeKeyboard);
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/BOTTOKEN/sendmessage?chat_id=CHATID&reply_markup=".$removeKeyboardEncoded")
```

The URL logic is the same in Python as it is in PHP, you just have to adjust the JSON encode function (...).

### Update

I learned Python in the last two years so here's the actual code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

removeKeyboard = {'remove_keyboard':True}
removeKeyboardEncoded = json.dumps(removeKeyboard)
urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.telegram.org/BOTTOKEN/sendmessage?chat_id=CHATID&text=MESSAGE&reply_markup=" + removeKeyboardEncoded).read()
```

In the current version of the Bot API you now have to add the `text` parameter -or else you get a `Bad Request: message text is empty`- but the rest works like it worked back then.

Answer (score 1):

You can [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) via HTTPS request with [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove).

Comment: I know what it is called, but I tried it and it doesn't work. How exactly has the  url to look like?